# How do I get the list of tables in my BigQuery dataset in a Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm writing a Google AppsScript and am having trouble getting a list of the tables in my DataSet.

Here is my code...

```
function GetTablesList(){
  var tableList = BigQuery.Tables.list('crave-production','Rons_ODBC_Test')
  Logger.log('tableListItemCount:', tableList.totalItems)
}
```

It returns nothing after the 'tableListItemCount:' label.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this `Logger.log('tableListItemCount:', tableList.totalItems)` should be this `Logger.log('tableListItemCount: %s', tableList.totalItems)`

Comment: That was the issue.  Thanks